# Is automatic indent available for a notepad?

Tags: notepad

I am a windows 7 user. I need an automatic indent option for my notepad similar to that of the ubuntu gedit. Is that possible by any means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in the built-in Notepad app.

I'd recommend ditching Notepad and using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) instead. Both can do what you want, as well as much, much more. They are comparable in many ways, but Notepad++ is free, while Sublime Text is not. Sublime Text has a few features not in Notepad++, but I'd recommend trying out Notepad++ first and seeing how you like it. I switched to it years ago and never use the built-in Notepad anymore.

Comment: ["Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use."](https://www.sublimetext.com/buy) Just because they don't enforce a fixed time limit doesn't mean it's free.

Comment: I retract my previous statement then. At any rate, you did answer the question, in the sense Notepad doesn't have an automatic indent feature. Any other answer would most likely be a product/software recommendation.